# Spring JDBC - SELECT on table after executing stored procedure

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I have a scenario where my service executes a stored procedure which populates a certain database table (let's call it `SERVICE_TABLE`, and after it is executed, the same service perform a query on this table.

Procedure execution code (some information was ommited due to company's policies, but the method is exactly the same):

```java
public void executeStoredProcedure(String schema,
                                    String procedure,
                                    Map<String, Object> params) {

    final SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
        .withProcedureName(procedure);

    if (schema != null) {
        jdbcCall.withSchemaName(schema);
    }

    final SqlParameterSource parameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource(params);
    jdbcCall.execute(parameterSource);
}
```

Then, the following SQL is executed against this table:

```sql
select *
from SERVICE_TABLE
```

The issue I'm facing is: executing the SQL through the service returns an empty list, while executing it directly on the database through SQL Developer, returns the correct values. I've tried using Spring's `@Transactional` decorators, but without any success.

If I place a breakpoint directly into the service code when it's about to execute the query, and try to run it through IntelliJ's evaluate option, the first couple of tries returns the same empty list, but after that, it starts returning the correct value list.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you need to flush your Database changes first before querying them using your Entity Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue.

The procedure was being invoked due to an external scheduled job, causing data being synchronized wrongly.

Thanks for the help.